# Debugging moonlight firefox plugin in linux using gdb

Tags: linux, debugging, mono, gdb, moonlight

I am trying to debug the default libmoonplugin.so added to firefox in gdb on ubuntu platform.
I am able to assign a breakpoint but get following error when breakpoint hits:

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

Can anyone help me out please ?
Thanks,
Siddharth

Comment: you are probably not hitting the breakpoint, do a backtrace and check stack frame, see where u are getting the crash.

Comment: Can you show the complete output of the gdb session?

Comment: Hi  AUZKamath and  Rolf Bjarne thanks for your quick replies, Here is the complete output of gdb
(gdb) file libmoonplugin.so 
A program is being debugged already.
Are you sure you want to change the file? (y or n) y
Reading symbols from /usr/local/lib/moonlight/plugin/libmoonplugin.so...done.
Unsupported JIT protocol version in descriptor!
(gdb) run default.html 
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program:libmoonplugin.so default.html
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000002 in ?? ()

Comment: is it possible to attach the complete trace in a text file ? Thanks